# A magical operation

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

A magical operation on a particular number (not ending by 0) is the addition of this number with his symetrical number. For example the magical operation for 2018 would be 2018 + 8102 = 10120.

Let us choose a number with first digit (left one) strictly inferior to his last digit (right one). We do a magical operation on this number To get a second number and then a magical operation on this second number To get a third number and so on.

Knowing the sixth number is 17347. Can you guess the first number?

Source: tangente magazine december 2017.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The possible strings of magical operations are:

> `(first) 143 -> 484 -> 968 -> 1837 -> 9218 -> 17347 (sixth)`
>
>  `(first)  89 -> 187 -> 968 -> 1837 -> 9218 -> 17347 (sixth)`

Rigorous proof follows...

Let's first make a few starting observations regarding the left and right numbers for a given number (result) and the number it is created from by a magical operation (operand):

> 1) If the left number of the result is 1 then the left and right numbers of the operand must either sum to 10 or more, or sum to 9 with a 1 carried from the addition of any middle numbers.
>
>  2) If the left number of the result is 1 more than the right number, then the left and right numbers of the operand must sum to the right number of the result, with a 1 carried from the addition of any middle numbers.
>
>  3) If the left and right numbers of the result are equal, then the left and right numbers of operand must sum to one of them, and there is no carried 1 from the addition of any middle numbers.
>
>  Any combination of left and right numbers for the result that don't meet the above criteria can't be formed by any operand.

Starting with the **sixth number** as `17347`, then we can say that the fifth number must be...

> a 4-digit number, since there is no 5-digit number that can produce the sixth number after a magical operation. The only two single-digit numbers that can produce 17 are 8 and 9, so the fifth number has to be `9ab8`. The 9 has to be on the left so the numbers that sum to 8 on the right (from the prior magical operation on the fourth number) can be incremented by a carried 1. We can also determine that `a` and `b` have to sum to 3, and that the carried one that creates the 9 will also be added to `a`, making `a` one larger than `b`. The only solution is `a=2` and `b=1`.
>
>  This gives us the **fifth number**: `9218`

This then leads us to the fourth number...

> which also has to be a 4-digit number `abcd`. We know that `a` and `d` have to add to 8, and `b` and `c` have to add to 11, and are therefore different numbers. Let's first consider the possible values for `a` and `d`. The combinations `2bc6`, `3bc5`, `5bc3`, `6bc2`, and `7bc1` are immediately out since there are no combination of numbers in a 3-digit or 4-digit third number that could make those. If it's `4bc4`, then a 4-digit third number would have to be either `1gh3`, `2gh2`, or `3gh1`, and there are no combinations of `g` or `h` that could produce two *different* values for `b` and `c` (since there can be no carried 1).
>
>  The only option left for the fourth number is `1bc7`. This would be created by a third number `xyz` where `x` and `z` would have to add to create a `7` on the right and a `1` on the left, and we know from above this would mean it's `9y8`. The value for `b` could be either `7` if `y+y+1` is less than 10, or `8` if `y+y+1` is greater than 10. Since `b+c` must be 11, the only combination that works is `b=8`, `c=3`, and `y=6`.
>
>  This gives us the **fourth number**: `1837`
>
>  As well as the **third number**: `968`

Now onto the second number(s)...

> which have to be a 3-digit number `a8c`, where `a+c` equals 8 and the middle number is 8 to produce a carried 1. As above, the options `286`, `385`, `583`, `682`, and `781` are out since there are no 2-digit or 3-digit first numbers that can result in those. We're left with `484` or `187`.
>
>  This gives us two possibilities for a **second number**: `187` and `484`

And now onto the first number(s)...

> For a second number `484` the first number must be a 3-digit number `a4c`, where `a+c` is 4 and `a` must be strictly less than (not equal to) `c`. Only `a=1` and `c=3` satisfy this.
>
>  For a second number `187`, only a first number `89` works, since `98` has a left number greater than the right.
>
>  This gives us two possibilities for a **first number**: `89` and `143`

Answer (score 11):

I'd guess:

> 49, 58 or 67
>  As they all seem to work unless I'm missing something.

Going backwards from 17347:

> The previous number has to be 9ab8 or 8cd9.
>  So two numbers before that is 9x8 or 8y9.
>  So number before that is 4z4. Where z causes a carry.
>  484 works forward to 17347 and one number backwards is 143.
>  49, 58 and 67 all magic to 143 obeying the first digit less than the last rule.

EDIT:

> Too much magic! Thank you @Untitpoi.  My not-totally-correct answer should be 143. (please see @gnovice's answer for the correct solution)

Comment: What you age missing la that there is only 5 magical operation and you made 6 so 17347 would be the seventh number in your answer

Answer (score 0):

> The answer is 121
>
>  121 +  121 =   242
>  242 +  242 =   484
>  484 +  484 =   968
>  968 +  869 =  1837
>  1837 + 7381 =  9218
>  9218 + 8129 = 17347
>
>  4 digit numbers: abcd+dbca can be abstracted to 1001x + 110y where x = a+d and y = b+c
>  3 digit numbers uvw+wvu can be abstracted to 101x + 20 y  where x = u+w and y = v

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you hide your answer in spoiler tags to avoid spoiling your solution for others, please?

Comment: You neglected to follow one of the rules of the puzzle.  "Let us choose a number with first digit (left one) strictly inferior to his last digit (right one). "